# requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found

Tags: python, web-scraping

i need to find only urls of clinics from this page. I know the last line is wrong, but how to fix it?

```
url = "https://www.dent.cz/zubni-lekari"


s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=1)
# print(r.status_code)
# print(r.text)


clinics = r.html.xpath(
    '//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div', first=True)


for item in clinics.absolute_links:
    r = s.get(item)
    print(r.html.find("div.box-detail", first=True).text)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using their Ajax API to get URLs of dental clinics (not every clinic has web though):

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://is-api.dent.cz/api/v1/web/workplaces"

payload = {
    "deleted": False,
    "filter": "accepts_new_patients=false",
    "fulltext": "",
    "page": 1,                     # <--- you can implement pagination via this parameter
    "per_page": 30,
    "sort_fields": "name",
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()
for item in data["data"]:
    print("{:<50} {}".format(item["name"], item["contact"]["web"] or "N/A"))
```

Prints:

```
#staycool s.r.o.                                   N/A
0-100 DENT s.r.o.                                  N/A
0-100 DENT s.r.o.                                  N/A
1. LF Dental s.r.o.                                N/A
1. LF Dental s.r.o.                                N/A
1. zubní s.r.o.                                    N/A
100mikro s.r.o.                                    N/A
1A Bučovice Dent s.r.o.                            N/A
2 Dent s.r.o.                                      N/A
2D dent s.r.o.                                     www.2d-dent.cz
2H dent s.r.o.                                     www.2hdent.cz
2-K DENT s.r.o.                                    http://www.2kdent.cz
2orto s.r.o.                                       N/A
32 Dent s.r.o.                                     N/A
3DImplant s.r.o.                                   N/A
3DImplant s.r.o. -  Za pruhy 243/2, Praha 4        N/A
3DK s.r.o.                                         N/A
3G Dent s.r.o.                                     N/A
3HMHK, s.r.o.                                      N/A
3HPHK s.r.o.                                       N/A
3KDENT s.r.o.                                      N/A
7DENT s.r.o.                                       N/A
A Cappella dental s.r.o.                           www.acdental.cz
A&S Dental Clinic, spol. s r.o.                    N/A
A+A Dent s.r.o.                                    N/A
A+A Dent s.r.o.                                    N/A
A2STOM s.r.o.                                      budecska.cz
AAA-dent s.r.o.                                    www.aaa-dent.eu
AB Stomatologie s.r.o.                             N/A
AB Zubní ordinace, s.r.o.                          N/A
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, can we consult something?